# How to upload video or image file to database

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am working in a project in which i need to create api using nodejs to upload video or image file to the postgres database
How i can do this
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure you want to store a file within the database? I would store it in the file system and the filename in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an image or video to base64, and then upload the base64 encoded string to your database.

```
const fs = require('fs');

function encode_base64(file) {
    const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}

const image = encode_base64('image.jpg');
const video = encode_base64('image.mp4');
```

Comment: And how i can convert it back to the original file